# How to make the sql run faster?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, row-number

I use SQL Server 2008 and my SQL query looks like this:

```
select * from (
select row_number() over(PARTITION by tb01.P_USER order by tb04.P_data7 desc) Row
  ,tb01.P_USER as 'enterpriseID'
  ,tb01.P_ID as 'greenhouseID'
  ,tb01.P_NAME as 'greenhouseName'
  ,tb04.P_data1 as 'airTemp'
  ,tb04.P_data2 as 'airHi'
  ,tb04.P_data3 as 'soilTemp'
  ,tb04.P_data4 as 'soilHi'
  ,tb04.P_data5 as 'co'
  ,tb04.P_data6 as 'sun'
  ,tb04.P_data7 as 'pickingTime'
  ,tb05.P_data5 as 'params'
from TB04 tb04,TB01 tb01,TB05 tb05,TB12 tb12
 where tb04.P_data8 = tb05.P_data2 
 and tb05.P_data1=tb01.P_ID
 and tb01.P_USER = tb12.P_data1
 and tb12.CodeId = '410621'
 ) result where Row between (3-1)*20+1 and 3*20
```

I want to pick out 20 of them but when I ran this SQL, it took about 8 seconds, which, of course were out of our expectations.

Would any one help me ?thx.

Edited:
I have removed the "PARTITION by tb01.P_USER" and its query speed doubled.
now the exec plan lists below:
[image]

The sorting takes 98% of the querying time, What should i do for this? should I remove the over function and use another more effective method if I have to?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago)

Comment: I know that.I just take the code form others hand AND I have to modify this.

Comment: @marc_s thx for editting this.Now I removed "PARTITION by tb01.P_USER", its query speed doubled.

Comment: Have you look at execution plans to see where the time is spent in this query?

Comment: @marc_s the execution plans list above.

Comment: From the "RID..(Heap)" and the table scans (top right), it looks like you don't have any clustering keys at all in your model. Try adding some **good** clustering keys to your tables! Clustered tables are generally faster than heaps (which are really a mess... avoid them if ever possible).

Comment: Read [Kimberly Tripp's blog post 'More considerations for the clustering key'](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/more-considerations-for-the-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) to learn what a **good** clustering key is (narrow, unique, static, fixed-length, ever-increasing)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38010/discussion-between-charlieshi-and-marc-s)

Comment: @marc_s, I added the clustering keys, but the exec plans remain the same as above. any advice?

Comment: Another "best practice" is to have indexes on all foreign key columns to make JOIN's faster. So any column that's referencing another table's primary key should be indexed, too.

Comment: You have a query thats selects a bunch of stuff, then filters out everything except when rownumber is between 41 and 60 -- how many rows would be selected if you omit this where clause? i.e., is it a data volume problem?

Comment: @GaryWalker  there are about 1000000 records

Answer (score 0):

I have a complete series of blog posts regarding SQL performance. Check part 3 and part 4 for some insights: http://www.karafilis.net/sql-indexing-part3/

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't read Chinese, I really can't interpret your execution plan, but I suspect most of the effort in the sort is being discarded when you finally select 20 records out of a million. I would assume that you are doing this to support paging for a web app or a smart client.

1) Is this something you can compute once per day and simply store results?

2) Rewrite the query using a modern ansi join and migrate as many "where" parameters into the the ON clauses of the joins as possible. I know it should not matter in theory, but I have often seen the query optimizer do a better job when written this way.

3) Selecting 20 rows out of a million in your case is essentially arbitrary since you don't have an order by clause in your select statement. SQL server does not guarantee the sort order will be consistent without an order by clause, in practice you will get this data in the same order each time you select it until the table statistics change so that the query optimizer changes the execution plan or is decides to rehash a hashed index. Either of these things can basically occur at arbitrary times.

4) The only thing restricting the million rows selected (not counting rowif) in your query is tb12.CodeId = '410621'.  If this is the best you can do, ok. But are you sure you are not overlooking something, perhaps even a case you knowing more than than query optimizer?